# Disk size issue

Tags: size

i am confused with size and size on disk, both are same or different, As shown in folder properties it show both,

[Just have a look here](http://jan.imghost.us/7f2g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size is the actual size of the file in bytes. 
size on disk is the actual amount of space being using on the disk. And the disk is broken down into tracks and sectors.

So, if your sectors size is 512 bytes and your file is actually 513 bytes, the size on disk will be 1024bytes because it is occupying two sectors.